# If $x$, $|x+1|$, $|x-1|$ are three terms of an arithmetic progression, what is its sum upto 20 terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't figure out how to work with the modulus in this problem.

The answer is (180 or 350).

Comment: x= -1.5, d=2, sum = 350, x= -0.5,d=1,sum = 180

Comment: How did you obtain the values for x?

Comment: From Ross Millikan's answer, sorry first x -2<x<-1, second -1<x<0. I just assign that value. In first case if x <-2 then it is not an AP and for x in range -2<x<-1  got same sum 350.  In second case if x > 1  then it is not an AP and for x in range -1<x<0  got same sum 180.

Answer (score 2):

Start by finding the ranges of $x$ where the signs are constant. For example, if $x \gt 1,$ the terms inside the modulus sign are positive, so your terms are $x, x+1, x-1$, but that doesn't work. The other choices are $x \lt -1$ and $-1 \lt x \lt 1$. In each one you know the signs, so can remove the modulus.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

We have $2|x+1|=x+|x-1|$

As $|a|=+a$ for real $a\ge0,$ else $|a|=-a$

consider if $x<-1,-1\le x<1, x\ge1$